# Android relative layout with DP pixels misarranged whole layout for different screens

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am using Relative layout with dp (dentisy pixels). Which is ideal for all screen. But on android htc desire it looks fine but on other phones half of the screen is visible.

I am putting my xml file here for clearity .

With this xml in Htc desire everything look fine but on other phone say samsung small screen one buttons not shown. i.e. half of the screen visible. What i am doing wrong?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/chosenstore">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/youhavechosen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="You have chosen:" />
```

```
    android:layout_below="@+id/youhavechosen"
    android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textColor="#666666"
    android:text="The Money Shop" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvLocConfirmStreet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvLocTheMoneyShop"
    android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
    android:textColor="#666666"
    android:text="TextView" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvLocConfirmTown"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/tvLocConfirmStreet"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvLocConfirmStreet"
     android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textColor="#666666"
    android:text="TextView" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvLocConfirmPostCode"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvLocConfirmTown"
     android:layout_below="@+id/tvLocConfirmTown"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textColor="#666666"
     android:text="TextView" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvLocConfirmTele"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvLocConfirmPostCode"
     android:layout_below="@+id/tvLocConfirmPostCode"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textColor="#666666"
     android:text="TextView" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvLocConfirmOpeningTime"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvLocConfirmTele"
     android:layout_below="@+id/tvLocConfirmTele"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:textSize="15dp"
     android:text="Opening Time:"
      android:textColor="#666666"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvMon"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvLocConfirmOpeningTime"
     android:layout_below="@+id/tvLocConfirmOpeningTime"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textColor="#666666"
     android:text="Mon:" />
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvTue"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvMon"
     android:layout_below="@+id/tvMon"
      android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textColor="#666666"

     android:text="Tue:" />
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvWed"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvLocConfirmOpeningTime"
     android:layout_below="@+id/tvTue"
      android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textColor="#666666"
     android:text="Wed:" />
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvThur"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvLocConfirmOpeningTime"
     android:layout_below="@+id/tvWed"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textColor="#666666"
     android:text="Thur:" />
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvFri"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvLocConfirmOpeningTime"
     android:layout_below="@+id/tvThur"
      android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textColor="#666666"
     android:text="Fri:" />
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvSat"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvLocConfirmOpeningTime"
     android:layout_below="@+id/tvFri"
      android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textColor="#666666"
     android:text="Sat:" />
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvSun"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvLocConfirmOpeningTime"
     android:layout_below="@+id/tvSat"
      android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#666666"
     android:text="Sun:" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvLocConfirmMon"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvMon"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvMon"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvMon"
     android:text="TextView"
      android:textColor="#666666"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvLocConfirmTue"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvTue"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvTue"
      android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textColor="#666666"
     android:text="TextView" />
   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvLocConfirmWed"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvWed"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvWed"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textColor="#666666"
     android:text="TextView" />
     <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvLocConfirmThur"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvThur"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvThur"
      android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#666666"
     android:text="TextView" />
       <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvLocConfirmFri"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvFri"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvFri"
      android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textColor="#666666"
     android:text="TextView" />
         <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvLocConfirmSat"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvSat"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvSat"
      android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textColor="#666666"
     android:text="TextView" />
           <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvLocConfirmSun"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvSun"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvSun"
      android:textColor="#666666"
      android:textStyle="bold"
     android:text="TextView" />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/collect"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               android:layout_below="@+id/tvLocConfirmSun"
               android:layout_marginTop="1dp"

               android:background="@drawable/collectherebutton"
               />
              <Button
               android:id="@+id/storeDetail"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               android:layout_below="@+id/collect"
               android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

               android:background="@drawable/storedetailbutton"
               />

              <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/locConfirmImage"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

                  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvLocTheMoneyShop"
                  android:src="@drawable/locicon" />

              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/mapButton"
                  style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvLocConfirmTele"
                  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                  android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
                  android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: I tried to edit your post for fixing the XML formatting, but it wouldn't let me. Could you indent the root RelativeLayout and the one TextView tag correctly?

Comment: I dont know why its not letting you to edit. Anyways you think tags are not correctly written?

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure that there are at least 4 space characters in front of each line of your XML block. Just look at the formatted result of your post. It shows up as 3 distinct blocks of code, the root tag "RelativeLayout" is missing for example. In between must be another two formatting mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a scroll view before first text view, and end just before your relative layout closing tag. This will sort it out.